# Is AWS Sage Maker Auto Pilot suitable for NLP?

Tags: nlp, amazon-sagemaker

Is AWS Sage Maker Auto Pilot suitable for NLP?

We currently have a tensorflow model that does classification on input of a sequence of URLS (
We transform the URLs to Word vec and Char vec to feed it to the model).

Looking at Sage Maker Auto Pilot documentation it says that it works on input in tabular form.
I was wondering if we could use it to for our use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. SageMaker AutoPilot doesn't support deep learning at the moment, only classification and regression problems on tabular data. Technically, I guess you could pass embeddings in CSV format, and pray that XGBoost figures them out, but I seriously doubt that this would deliver meaningful results :)

Amazon Comprehend does support fully managed custom classification models https://docs.aws.amazon.com/comprehend/latest/dg/how-document-classification.html. It may be worth taking a look at it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I found Google's fully managed text classification offering to perform much better than AWS's equivalent. I'm sure it depends on your domain, but thought I'd mention.

https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/beginners-guide